# Castor library JAR

Tags: jar, castor

I have a serious problem, I need the JAR version 1.3.3 or 1.4.1 of :
castor (mainly),
castor ddlgen,
castor codegen and
castor anttasks

I as looking for these but I just found version 1.2 and. lower.
It would be great if some of you can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Havent used that lib but the general workflow is

option 1
In docs for that lib https://github.com/castor-data-binding/castor
it says you can download jar files from Sonatype's OSS snapshot 
so go to that link 
https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/org/codehaus/castor/castor-core/ 
https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/org/codehaus/castor/castor-anttasks/
and browse around. Here you can find those versions

I guess you are not using maven. You have to use ant or something. In that case you can still to this

option 2
Go to maven repo 
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.castor
Pick what lib you need for example 
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.castor/castor-xml/1.4.1
and in table you can find links to jars to download

option 3
If you cant find on maven repo that lib. You can still clone that maven project, and run maven install and it will build jar files locally for you. After that just copy them

Comment: thanks for your help @bevelod, I've already try option 1 and 2, there are not JARs. 
I will try option 3 again, first time I couldn't